# Get floating div to vertical align

Tags: html, css, z-index, vertical-alignment

Here's the challenge I'm facing.  I'm trying to get a div to appear behind another object and to center align to it.

This is what I'm up to so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/GYha2/

And this is the result I'm trying to get

[image]

As you can see, I'm close.  I just can't get it to align center and to position itself behind the other object.

Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<div id="banner" class="grid_12">
    <div class="bannerBgT"></div>
    <div class="bannerBgY">
        <div id="planPricingWrapper">
            <div id="planPrices">
                <div class="planPrice">
                    <div class="planPriceX"> </div>
                    <div class="planPriceR"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear_10px"></div>
                <div class="planPrice">
                    <div class="planPriceX"> </div>
                    <div class="planPriceR"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="planPriceOptions">
                <div class="planPriceOptionsBgT" id="supremacy"></div>
                <div class="planPriceOptionsBgY" id="supremacy">
                    <div><img src="http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/images/plans/pricing_title_supremacy.png" width="183" height="27" alt="Supremacy" id="titleImg" /></div>
                    <img src="http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/images/plans/pricing_plan_supremacy.png" width="146" height="156" alt="" />
                    <div class="planFeatures"> <b>Includes Gold &amp; Platinum Features Plus:</b>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Class 3 Rayhawk Design</li>
                            <li>Class 3 Content Management</li>
                            <li>Up to 6 Content Modules</li>
                            <li>Inclusion in 2 or more directories/portals</li>
                            <li>Access to Rayhawk brand management services*</li>
                            <li>Mobile device enabled educational content/videos</li>
                            <li>Marketing materials deployment system*^</li>
                            <li>2 hours per month of additional services</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="planPriceOptionsBgB" id="supremacy"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerBgB"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#planPricingWrapper {
    padding: 20px;
}

#planPrices {
    float: right;
}

#planPrices * {
    z-index: 1;
}

.planPrice > * {
    float: left;
}

.planPriceX {
    width: 280px;
    height: 131px;
    background: url(http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/images/plans/pricing_bg_x.png) repeat-x;
}

.planPriceR {
    width: 11px;
    height: 131px;
    background: url(http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/images/plans/pricing_bg_r.png) no-repeat;
}

#planPriceOptions {
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.planPriceOptionsBgT, .planPriceOptionsBgB {
    width: 614px;
}

.planPriceOptionsBgT#supremacy, .planPriceOptionsBgY#supremacy, .planPriceOptionsBgB#supremacy {
    background-color: #181818;
}

.planPriceOptionsBgT {
    height: 10px;
    background: url(http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/images/plans/pricing_plan_bg_t.png) no-repeat;
}

.planPriceOptionsBgY {
    background: url(http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/images/plans/pricing_plan_bg_y.png) repeat-y;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 574px;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.planPriceOptionsBgY #titleImg {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.planPriceOptionsBgB {
    height: 12px;
    background: url(http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/images/plans/pricing_plan_bg_b.png) no-repeat;
}

.planFeatures {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: square;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.planFeatures ul {
    list-style: square;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do vertically aligning:

1. Use tables (using either real HTML `<table>` tags or fake CSS `display:table-cell` declarations)
2. Use inline elements (again, either real HTML elements that are naturally inline, like `<span>`, or CSS `display:inline-block` declarations)

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twMWh/2/) that uses `display:inline-block` to *approximately* get what you're after, I think. Notice that I also flipped around the two divs in the HTML.

It also uses the `*display:inline; zoom:1;` hack to make it work with IE6/7

Comment: I've made a few attempts to do this but I'm running into problems with `float`s and `clear`s.

Comment: @imoda Can you post a new fiddle demonstrating what you've tried? Notice also that I got rid of the `float:right` that you had on `#planPrices`

Comment: This is what I'm working with now. http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/GYha2/2/ & http://www.patientacquisitionsystem.com/plans.php?page=pricing

Comment: @imoda [Here's a modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvPqG/) that does its best. However, there are a number of issues that need to be addressed. The most glaring is that you'll have white space appear on the top and bottom if `#planPrices` is taller than its corresponding `.planPriceOptionsBgY`.